# Python Versions on Mac

Tags: python, macos, version, homebrew

I'm working on Mac Os 10.7 (Lion) and I have some questions:

1. What is the pre-installed version of python on Lion?
2. I've been working on this computer for some time now, and i've installed lots of software in order to do college work many times I didn't know what I was really doing. The thing is: now I hava on the /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/ a folder called "7.0" I'm pretty sure there no python version 7. Is this folder native or a third-part program installation. Can I delete it? (it's using 1 Gb on disk).
3. Where is located the original python that comes with mac os?
4. I've choose Homebrew as my package manager, is there a easy way to manage python versions with it?

Comment: Open a command terminal and type python, it will tell you the version

Comment: 2. Some application (enthought maybe?) installed 7.0. Deleting it will for sure break some installed software, however it will not affect OSX itself. Another thing to check is the path and pythonpath variables (typ "echo $PATH" and "echo $PYTHONPATH" in a Terminal).

Comment: That was it! enthought! Thanks!

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH shows nothing

Comment: just for reference... why my question was voted down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Lion uses Python 2.7 by default; 2.5 and 2.6 are also available.
2. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` does not exist on a stock install of Lion. My guess is that you've ended up with this by installing some application.
3. The default Python install is primarily installed in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`, although some components are located elsewhere.
4. Yes - you can `brew install python@2` to get a Python 2.7 separate from the system version, or `brew install python` to get Python 3.7. Both will install to `/usr/local`, like any other Homebrew recipe.

Answer (score 8):

1. I think that is Python 2.7 but you can check typing python on a command terminal. It will tell you the version.
2. I couldn't tell that you can deleting it, because I don't know what it has... can you give more info about it?
3. Just type "which python" and it will tell you
4. You should use virtualenv and pip: http://jontourage.com/2011/02/09/virtualenv-pip-basics/